# How to get the 3rd element after doing a split

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, formula, power-platform

I have this formula to concatenation and get the last element after doing a split:-

```
concat(body('GetRootFolder')['d']['ServerRelativeUrl'], '/', 'Closed','/',last(split(items('Apply_to_each'),'#;')))
```

But my question is how can get I the 3rd element inside the split array instead of the last element ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can access a specific numbered element in an array using JSON notation. For example the following would return the 3rd element in the zero based array:

```
split(items('Apply_to_each'),'#;')[2]
```

So as long as you know what N is, you can access the Nth item by typing JSON into the expressions tab where the index number is N-1.

Comment: this will raise an syntax error

Comment: can you show us the current expression you are using and add screenshot of error message to original question?